# How to Include zero-count when joining 3 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have 3 tables: Vehicle, type and color

**Vehicle**

```
id  brand   type_id color_id
1   Toyota     1       2
2   Toyota     2       3
3   GMC        2       1
4   BMW        2       1
```

**Type**

```
id  name
1   Truck
2   Car
```

**Color**

```
id  name
1   White
2   Red
3   Black
```

I want to get the count of each combination of type and color including 0 values, like this:

```
type.name   color.name          count
Truck         White               0
Truck          Red                1
Truck         Black               0
Car           White               2
Car            Red                0
Car           Black               1
```

I tried this query below

```
SELECT type.name, color.name, count(vehicle.id) count
FROM vehicle
RIGHT JOIN type on vehicle.type_id = type.id
RIGHT JOIN color on color.id = vehicle.color_id
GROUP BY type.name, color.name
```

but it doesn't produce zero values:

```
type.name   color.name          count
Truck          Red                1
Car           White               2
Car           Black               1
```

Is there a neat query to achieve the first results?

Comment: Most people find main table LEFT JOIN optional data much easier to understand than optional data RIGHT JOIN main table.

Comment: You need to first create a data set with all the colours and name, and then `LEFT JOIN` from that.

Comment: cross join type and color, then outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mention @jarlh in comments, this can be done using `CROSS JOIN` :

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT t.id as type_id, t.name as type_name, c.id as color_id, c.name as color_name
  FROM type t
  CROSS JOIN color c
)
SELECT c.type_name, c.color_name, count(t.color_id) as count
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN vehicle t on t.type_id = c.type_id and t.color_id = c.color_id
GROUP BY c.type_name, c.color_name
order by c.type_name desc, c.color_name desc
```

Or simply :

```
SELECT t.name as type_name, c.name as color_name, count(v.id) as count
FROM type t
CROSS JOIN color c
LEFT JOIN vehicle v on v.type_id = t.id and v.color_id = c.id
GROUP BY t.name, c.name
order by t.name desc, c.name desc
```

Results :

```
type_name   color_name  count
Truck       White       0
Truck       Red         1
Truck       Black       0
Car         White       2
Car         Red         0 
Car         Black       1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iN2dssNd)

Comment: I'd even skip the cte and simply do `FROM type CROSS JOIN color LEFT JOIN vehicle ON...`.

Comment: Yes, You are right

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it.

with record_count as (

select 
b.id [typeid], 
b.name [typename], 
c.id [colorid], 
c.name, 
[colorname], 
count(*) record_count 
from vehicle a 
left join type b on a.type_id = b.id 
left join color c on a.color_id = c.id 
group by b.id, b.name, c.id, c.name

)

select a.typename, a.colorname, isnull(b.record_count,0) count 
from ( 

select distinct type.id [typeid],  type.name [typename], color.id 
 [colorid], color.name [colorname] 
from vehicle , type, color

) as a

left join record_count b on a.typeid = b.typeid 
and a.colorid = b.colorid